# "TypeError: c1.levels is undefined" when drawing triangles in p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I've been trying to recreate a program in p5.js that draws triangles on your screen, much like this:

[image: Picture of polygon demo from code.pen]

It's based on [code I found](https://codepen.io/brondbjerg/pen/bVNzOp) on codepen.io by Mike Brondbjerg, but I changed a few things while I was going through it. When I first tried running the code straight from his project on my own computer, it didn't work at all, so I spent the morning editing it to become this new version, shown below.

```
var img;
var xPos = [];
var yPos = [];
var sampleRate = 8; 
var shapePoints = 3; 

var frames = 0;

function preload() {
    img = loadImage("zebra.png");
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 600);
    smooth();
    noStroke();
    background(0);
}

function draw() {

    frames = frames + 1;

    if (frames >= sampleRate) {

        frames = 0;

        xPos.push(mouseX);
        yPos.push(mouseY);

        if (xPos.length >= shapePoints) {
            var pixelA = img.get(xPos[xPos.length-1], yPos[yPos.length-1]);
            var pixelB = img.get(xPos[xPos.length-2], yPos[yPos.length-2]);
            var inbetweenCol = lerpColor(pixelA, pixelB, .5);
            fill(inbetweenCol);

        beginShape();
            for(var v=0; v<shapePoints; v++)
            {
                var arrayPos = xPos.length-1 - v;
                vertex(xPos[arrayPos],yPos[arrayPos]);
              }
        endShape(CLOSE);

        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try running it in my browser, it gives me an error that I've never, ever seen before.

[image: Error message as it appears on my browser's console]

Not much is coming up in my search engine either.

[image: Search engine results]

The files are organized in my directory like this:

```
directory_name 
 |__ lib
 |     |__ p5.js
 |___ index.html
 |___ sketch.js
 |___ zebra.png
```

And the html file is mostly empty, asides from the basic boilerplate code. I referenced the javascript files like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/lib/p5.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
```

Does **anyone** know what could have given me this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JavaScript console, to the right of the error, see the part that says `p5.js:6242:5`? Click it.

That will take you to the place in p5.js code that's causing the error, which will then tell you what in your code is causing the error.

You'll see that your problem is in the `lerpColor()` function: it's telling you that it's expecting a `levels` field inside the first parameter, but that field is missing.

In other words, your problem is here:

```
var pixelA = img.get(xPos[xPos.length-1], yPos[yPos.length-1]);
var pixelB = img.get(xPos[xPos.length-2], yPos[yPos.length-2]);
var inbetweenCol = lerpColor(pixelA, pixelB, .5);
```

The `img.get()` function returns an array that holds the R, G, B, and A values. The `lerpColor()` function doesn't work with arrays though. It only works with the `Color` type.

You need to convert the arrays to `Color` types, using the `color()` function. Then pass those `Color` types into the `lerpColor()` function:

```
var pixelA = img.get(xPos[xPos.length-1], yPos[yPos.length-1]);
var pixelB = img.get(xPos[xPos.length-2], yPos[yPos.length-2]);
var colorA = color(pixelA[0], pixelA[1], pixelA[2]);
var colorB = color(pixelB[0], pixelB[1], pixelB[2]);
var inbetweenCol = lerpColor(colorA, pixelB, .5);
```

Your error is happening because the `lerpColor()` function is trying to use the `levels` variable, which is defined inside the `Color` type. But since you're passing it an array instead of a `Color`, the `levels` variable is undefined.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining so clearly! Everything's working smoothly now :)